# HP Printer is not printing the file sent from java code

Tags: java, printing

I have the below code

```
public class PrinterExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintService printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService(); 
        System.out.println("Printer Name: " + printService.getName());  
        File file = new File("example1.xml");
        try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fis, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE, null);
            DocPrintJob printJob = printService.createPrintJob();
            printJob.addPrintJobListener(new LoggerPrintJobListener());
            printJob.print(doc, null);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            scanner.next();
        } catch(PrintException printException) {
            printException.printStackTrace();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
            fileNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose of the code is to send the text file "example1.xml" to the HP inkjet printer as byte stream and HP printer will print it. HP inkjet printer is configured as the default printer. I have listener class listening for event as shown below.

```
public class LoggerPrintJobListener implements PrintJobListener {

    // Your favorite Logger class goes here!
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(LoggerPrintJobListener.class.getName());


    public void printDataTransferCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        LOG.info("Print data transfer completed ;) ");
    }

    public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        LOG.info("Print job completed =) ");
    }

    public void printJobFailed(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        LOG.info("Print job failed =( ");
    }

    public void printJobCanceled(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        LOG.info("Print job canceled :| ");
    }

    public void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        LOG.info("No more events to the job ");
    }

    public void printJobRequiresAttention(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        LOG.info("Print job requires attention :O ");
    }
}
```

When i run the code I get the below output in the console and then waits for my input to exit

```
Printer Name: HP1244A1 (HP Ink Tank Wireless 410 series)
Jan 21, 2022 6:28:40 PM LoggerPrintJobListener printDataTransferCompleted
INFO: Print data transfer completed ;) 
Jan 21, 2022 6:28:40 PM LoggerPrintJobListener printJobNoMoreEvents
INFO: No more events to the job
```

According to console output the data is sent, but the HP Printer never prints the file. I am not able to understand what is happening.

Please help me out. I am stuck.

Comment: Maybe force it to a text file and not use AUTOSENSE. The printer may not know how to handle an XML

Comment: I tried and getting below error ```sun.print.PrintJobFlavorException: invalid flavor
 at sun.print.Win32PrintJob.print(Unknown Source)
 at printing.Example1.main(Example1.java:38)```